# Does leaving the brackets in a PHP if else structure improve speed?

Tags: php, performance

I am writing an algorithm where the difference of a couple of milliseconds does matter. I was wondering if the following first statement is faster, equal or slower than the following second statement:

First statement:

```
if( true )
{
    return true;
}
```

Second statement:

```
if( true )
    return true;
```

Does someone maybe also know a course about speed improvements?

Comment: If you really think you're at the point where you should even care about crap like this, your algorithms better.  be.  *Perfect.*  Thing is, i can safely guarantee they're not.

Comment: If you really care, though...what did your time trials say?

Comment: My time trials fluctuate to much to say for sure or there is a difference.

Comment: So the difference, if any, was literally so small that you measured it and could not even verify its existence.  Why are you still spending time thinking about this?

Comment: Because I am now testing with a subset, and the real dataset is about a 100 times bigger.

Comment: But your measurements are already so close that the noise of process switching and such dwarfs the difference.  That ratio isn't going to change.  You run it a hundred times as long, you'll see a hundred times as much not-a-difference and a hundred times as much of the noise.

Comment: True. So also taking in consideration the answer of Ed Cottrel, the difference is way to less to notice it. I am not worrying about it anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** No brackets *may be* faster, on the order of nanoseconds per cycle, at best, but is a terrible idea in terms of not introducing bugs and complexity down the road.

---

As a good reference, take a look at http://www.phpbench.com/. If and only if you have implemented **and tested** every one of those tweaks should you be worried about the potential nanosecond savings of this kind of thing.

You should seriously consider implementing [`OpCache`](http://php.net/opcache), as well, before obsessing over this kind of thing. `OpCache` stores the pre-compiled bytecode in memory. A bracket or no-bracket tweak is relevant only if the compiler isn't already optimizing it in the OpCache context.

Also, as @Abhineet says, you will make your code incomprehensible extremely quickly if you leave out the brackets.

**JUST BECAUSE**: Here's an answer. My benchmark code:

```
// Counting to 10,000,000, without brackets
$i=0;
$start = microtime(true);
while($i < 10000000) {
    if(true)
        $i++;
}
echo "<br>".( (int)((microtime(true) - $start)*1000) )." ms<br/>";

// Counting to 10,000,000, with brackets
$i=0;
$start = microtime(true);
while($i < 10000000) {
    if(true) {
        $i++;
    }
}
echo "<br>".( (int)((microtime(true) - $start)*1000) )." ms<br/>";
```

On my Dell laptop, running Windows 7, Apache/2.2.21, and PHP/5.3.9, the no-bracket version took 2081 ms, the bracketed version took 2765 ms. To verify, I ran it a few times and got results very close to these numbers each time. I also switched the order of the tests and got comparable results. But when I ran it on a different system running PHP 5.3.3, the reverse was true -- brackets was consistently faster. If you care that much about this, you are going to have to benchmark your code extensively on the specific machine, version of PHP, and configuration that you intend to use in production.

So, bottom line, you *might* be able to save about 0.7 seconds every ***10 million iterations***. Do with that what you wish...

### Updated Benchmarks

I stumbled upon this answer again and saw that (1) it's 3.5 years old and (2) my benchmarks were in PHP 5.3 (!). So, I decided to update them. In PHP 7+, this kind of micro-optimization is even more pointless. A couple of benchmarks:

In PHP 7.0.0, the difference is less than 4%, with numbers around 355 ms for 10 million iterations without brackets, versus 368 ms with brackets. That's a 0.013 s difference per 10 million iterations.

In PHP 7.1.5, it's even more absurd. I got numbers of 1326 ms for *100 million* iterations, versus 1331 ms. After the cache had warmed up, the difference was typically less than 2 ms and often 0 ms. In other words, in the current version of PHP, omitting the brackets saves you, at most, about 0.00000000002 s per `if` statement. In my opinion, that's nowhere near enough to justify the risk of introducing bugs and making the code harder to read.

Comment: The phpbench website was quite enlightening!

Answer (score 5):

**You should always use brackets.** There is no better way to make your code confusing and hard to read than by leaving off the brackets. There is also no significant performance hit either way, so far as I know.

Those two extra keys can mean a world of difference to somebody reading your code.

Ex:: For this code,

```
if( true )
    return true;
echo "Hello World!";
```

How will it look if you do,

```
if( true )
   // return true;
echo "Hello World!";
```

See, how fatal sometimes it can prove.

Comment: Completely agree. Or, at least, code blocks without curly braces should be written in a single line in order to be read as a single statement, without possibility to make mistakes as the one you've pointed out (line commenting). E.g.: `if (foo) return bar;`, or,  `for(...) dostuff();`

Comment: -1, Does not answer the question. Your advice should adjunct an answer instead of being the meat of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer: USE PSR-2**

This one is funny to me because it is faster NOT to use them, and  programmers here are almost unanimous to "always use them". However, when fretting over stripos or regex they defer to speed lol ... Both have nominal gains at best, hence should not be considered a priority unless warranted.

A different take:
I suggest that you adopt PSR2 and follow those rules strictly (which requires them).